# Invalid Value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Home'. It must be a valid React Component Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling, expo

I'm getting a Render Error on Expo Go that says 'Got an invalid value for 'component' propo for the screen 'Home'. It must be a valid React Component. Any advice??

This is my Home.js code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


export default function Home({ navigation, route}) {
    const [returnedParams, setReturnedParams] = useState(" ");

    useEffect( () => {
        if (route.params) {
            const myParams= route.params;
            setReturnedParams(myParams.sendBackParams);
        }
        
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text >Home Screen</Text>
        <Button title="Go to Details" onPress={ () => {
            navigation.navigate("Details", 
            {details: 'here are some more details about the home page'});
        }

        }></Button>
        <Text>{route.params?.sendBackParams}</Text>
        <Text>{returnedParams}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

Comment: Where are you importing the home component and setting it as a route/navigation

Comment: Noticed an extra space in `<Text >Home Screen</Text>`.

Comment: This extra space should not cause a problem

Comment: Can you share the code of where you are importing the Home component